# Как сделать набор инсталляторов нужных программ (включая PostgreSQL), чтобы ставить на Windows одним кликом?

Tags: windows, postgresql, windowsinstaller, inno-setup

Мне надо создать набор инсталяторов нужных мне программ (Postgressql, application), чтобы ставить на Windows одним кликом, делаю это с помощью программы Inno Setup.

Как это сделать? Есть какие нибудь примеры с Postgressql?

Comment: Ну так а в чём вопрос?

Comment: @donRumata сорри) дополнил вопрос... А вы работали с этим?

Answer (score 2):

1. Собирайте инсталяторы всех нужных программ.
2. Изучаете каждый из них на предмет наличия параметров запуска для тихой/автоматической установки.
3. Добавляем вызов всех инсталяторов с параметрами из своего инсталятора.
4. Если какой-то из инсталяторов не поддерживает автоматическую установку, запускаем его и ждем пока пользователь понажимает кнопочки.
5. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

Postgre и прочие средства и инструменты разработки или компоненты инфраструктуры вам было бы удобно переносить и разворачивать используя контейнеризацию. Это избавит вас от рутины и защитит вашу host-систему от повреждений. Посмотрите на Docker https://www.dockerbook.com